# How to improve the zipWith's performance in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, profiling, ghc

I've written a code for Clustering with Data.Clustering.Hierarchical, but it's slow.

I tried profiling and changing some of the code, but I don't know why `zipWith` is taking so many time? (even if, I change list to vector.)

```
import Data.Clustering.Hierarchical
import qualified Data.Vector.Primitive as DV
import System.Random
import Control.Monad


main = do
    vectorList <- genTestdata
    let cluster = dendrogram SingleLinkage vectorList getVectorDistance  
    putStrLn $ show cluster

genZero x 
    | x<5 = x
    |otherwise = 0

genVector::IO (DV.Vector Int)
genVector = do
    listRandom <- mapM (\x -> randomRIO (1,30) ) [1..20]
    let intOut = DV.fromList $ map genZero listRandom
    return intOut

genTestdata = do 
    r <- sequence  $ map (\x -> liftM (\y -> (x,y)) genVector) [1..1000]
    return r

getExp2 v1 v2 = d*d
    where
        d = v1 - v2

getExp v1 v2
    | v1 == v2 = 0
    | otherwise = getExp2 v1 v2

tfoldl  d = DV.foldl1' (+) d

changeDataType:: Int -> Double
changeDataType d = fromIntegral d

getVectorDistance::(a,DV.Vector Int)->(a, DV.Vector Int )->Double
getVectorDistance v1 v2 = fromIntegral $ tfoldl dat
    where
        l1 = snd v1
        l2 = snd v2
        dat = DV.zipWith getExp l1 l2
```

To build it, use: `ghc -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts -O2 log_cluster.hs`

Run with `log_cluster.exe +RTS -p`

The profiling result on my machine follows -- note the result for `getVectorDistance.dat`:

```
> log_cluster.exe +RTS -p -RTS

total time  =        8.43 secs   (8433 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 1,614,252,224 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE            MODULE  %time %alloc
getVectorDistance.dat  Main     49.4   37.8  <------
tfoldl                 Main      5.7    0.0
getExp                 Main      4.5    0.0
getExp2                Main      0.5    1.5
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would give some complete code that we can paste into a file and experiment with ourselves.  Not your whole project, just something that we can compile.

Comment: When trying to use profiling, I always like to start with a high-level  comparison of the profiling build to the non-profiling build.  E.g. build your executable both ways, and run it with `time` or similar.  It's helpful to get a good idea of how much overhead profiling introduces into your program.

Comment: Not reproducible, a small test shows only 11% alloc, and that's already with NOINLINE. As luqui said, add more information.

Comment: As per the vector docs: "Unboxed vectors of primitive types. The use of this module is not recommended except in very special cases. Adaptive unboxed vectors defined in Data.Vector.Unboxed are significantly more flexible at no performance cost." Also, give type signatures for your functions or you risk them being too polymorphic, which might (or might not) hurt performance. It also helps readability.

Comment: Hi every one, I had add testdada generator. So evey one can run the code now.

Comment: I should mention that the distinction between lists and vectors *is* generally important when dealing with `zipWith`. The short-cut fusion technique GHC uses for lists does not work so well for zips, whereas the stream fusion technique used for vectors does not work well for unzips.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the advice in my comment, here are timings for running the same code:

```
user:~/explorations$ ghc -O2 log_cluster.hs -rtsopts
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( log_cluster.hs, log_cluster.o )
Linking log_cluster ...
user:~/explorations$ time ./log_cluster
101000

real    0m0.127s
user    0m0.120s
sys     0m0.000s
```

and when built with profiling:

```
user:~/explorations$ ghc -prof -fprof-auto -O2 log_cluster.hs -rtsopts
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( log_cluster.hs, log_cluster.o )
Linking log_cluster ...
user:~/explorations$ time ./log_cluster
101000

real    0m2.937s
user    0m2.920s
sys     0m0.000s
```

So the profiled build is about 25 times slower, which is a pretty significant overhead.

At this point, I'm guessing the reason your program is slow is that you're building it for profiling.  If a non-profiled build is also too slow, you may need to use some more sophisticated profiling techniques.

Of course this is slightly conjectural as the code you provided doesn't compile, so I had to fill in some gaps.

Edit: To be clear, my position is that adding `SCC` annotations (whether manually or automatic) restricts the optimizations ghc can perform.  The more liberally they're applied, the greater the difference between the profiled code and the unprofiled code.  This can result in misleading profiles, since functions that appear as bottlenecks in the profiled code may be less so otherwise.  I think that's what's happening here.

The OP quite reasonably asks how to find the bottleneck if profiling results are so distorted.  I expect that for this example, `DV.zipWith` actually is a bottleneck because it's the only function that does significant work (see below wrt test generating code), however manual inspection of the core (produced by compiling with `-ddump-simpl -ddump-to-file -dsuppress-coercions`) shows that `getVectorDistance` produces a nice unboxed loop, with the intermediate vector completely fused away.  I doubt it can be significantly improved without heroic measures. (see note 2)

In general, the best way to use profiling is to start at the top and drill down.  You can either manually add a few `SCC` annotations near the top-level, or use `-fprof-auto-exported`, preferably specified only for a few key near-top-level modules, to get a rough idea.  From there you can drill down further, either by adding annotations to more modules, manually adding a few more `SCC` annotations, or, if you're feeling lucky, switching to `-fprof-auto`.  Unfortunately just using `-fprof-auto-exported` doesn't help much with this example unless you also add a `module Main (main, getVectorDistance)` statement.

An alternative is to use a different profiling method.  You could use e.g. [ghc-events-analyze](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/86/) to profile your code.  This involves manually adding some trace statements and post-processing the eventlog, but it usually interferes much less with compiler optimizations.  In pure code, it sometimes be tricky to figure out where to put statements so they're evaluated properly, my [chronograph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/chronograph) package can handle this (it doesn't support the ghc-events-analyze format yet but I'll add that soon).

I expect this is a cut-down example from the full code.  Hopefully one of these techniques will help find a bottleneck that can be more readily improved.

note 1: the data generating code can almost certainly be sped up, if it's similar to your full program.  `System.Random` is notoriously slow, use [mwc-random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random) or [mersenne-random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random).  I'm also slightly suspicious of using `DV.fromList`, but it might be fused away.

note 2: when compiled with `-prof -fprof-auto`, the core is not as good.  Instead of an unboxed loop over two vectors, first a *new* vector is created, then a loop traverses that new vector to calculate the sum.  So you have extra allocations, extra memory pressure, and two traversals instead of one.  This is why the profiled version is significantly slower, and also why I think the profile is misleading: the times for `DV.zipWith` are significantly inflated.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to know how to improve the performance of _one_ specific operation, since that operation takes most time and memory. This answer only shows that there are differences between profiled code and non-profiled code. The current version of the question should be closed, since it doesn't contain compileable code.

Comment: @Zeta: I'm suggesting that the answer to the OP's problem is to compile without profiling.  Profiled builds very frequently interfere with fusion-based systems like vector, so I think it's likely that will fix the issue.  Unfortunately you're correct that the question isn't very good in its current state.

Comment: Also, I think it's likely that the profile indicating `zipWith` is a bottleneck is misleading.  But similarly we can't know that for sure without a full, working example.

Comment: You are right. I try without profiling it is much faster. But in this situation how can I know where is the bottleneck?